# Cannot create different game characters in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to create a snake game where you can choose which character you want to be. I have the default character in my game set to be goomba. There is a "Characters" screen and from there, I want to be able to choose which character I want to be with buttons. I have tried to do

```
elif currentchar == "mario":
            charU = pygame.image.load('mario up')
            charD = pygame.image.load('mario down')
            charL = pygame.image.load('mario left')
            charR = pygame.image.load('mario right')
            gameLoop()
```

but it comes up with "NameError: name 'currentchar' is not defined". I don't know what to do if I define it.
The full code can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/7gtvdf8E
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

EDIT: oops I was tinkering a bit before pasting and forgot to change it. Here is the real pastebin https://pastebin.com/sYNHqPyD
EDIT: When i press "mario", nothing happens

Comment: Line 194, I believe you meant `currentchar = "mario"`, with a single `=` and not `==`. Also, the `elif` *after* that doesn't make sense. Are you sure the if block is correctly placed?

Comment: Yeah i meant to use one "=". It still doesnt work though. I don't know what to do.

Comment: In that case, your error will / should be different. If not, you should paste the full error traceback.

Comment: When I press Mario, nothing happens

Comment: Is there something unclear in my answer? If you work on your code and made the variables global you should in between see the change in what becomes displayed after you press Mario ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the new character pictures visible the function displaying them must know about the change happened in another function. That is where global variables comes in. If you make your variables global you will see the change and the code will work as you want.

Check out what the command `global` means and does here:

[Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Than put into in each function in which you have `charU`, `charD`, ... variables directly in the first line after `def functionName():` :

```
global charU, charD, charL, charR
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! This makes sense. I will test it tommorow. I am currently on my phone so I cannot test it now. If it works I'll give you best answer

Comment: If I do that, it comes up with syntax error on the =

Comment: Yes, you get a syntax error if you do the assigment first and the global declaration afterwards ... global must come first at the very top of the function body.

Comment: At the very top? Under def button or before all the images are loaded at the top?

Comment: There! Best Answer :)